# Why calling of Wait() of async function suspends my application, but if I use await all work good?

Tags: winforms, async-await, cefsharp

I have desktop application and I use cefsharp webbrowser

When I call: `chromiubwebbrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync().Wait()` - it suspends my application.
But if I call `await chromiubwebbrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync()` - all work good.

Why my application is suspended in first case and is not suspended in second case?

Comment: Because that's what the two operations are for. `Wait()` block the calling thread while waiting for the background operation to complete. `await` on the other hand releases the calling thread to do whatever it wants and resumes execution in the line after `await` when the background operation completes. In the case of Windows Forms, that means going back to the UI thread to execute the rest of the method

Comment: I removed the "task-parallel-library" tag as your question is not related to it.